# Meteor setInterval and query

Tags: javascript, meteor, setinterval

I want to have a function that checks every 5 seconds for all entries in database for some value is false and if finds then checks some logic condition and changes the value to true if the logic condition is met.
My function works well until I have something with `isItReady: false` in my collection. When I don't have, it obviously doesn't find anything and I start getting errors.

How should I do this correctly? I don't want to stop my interval because maybe something will be entered into the collection soon and then my inverval is stopped?

How can I do something like this:

If nothing matches my search criterea - `productDate = Products.findOne({isItReady: false});` the interval is stopped and as soon as something new gets inserted I will start the inverval again?

```
var logicCheck = Meteor.setInterval( function () {
                    productDate = Products.findOne({isItReady: false}); //query to find all entries with isItReady: false
                    var timeNow = Date();
                    var timeCreated = productDate.startOfCountdown;
                    timeCreated = timeCreated.toString(); //converts timeCreated from object to String(in Mongo its a object)
                    var productId = productDate._id;
                    console.log(typeof timeNow) //string
                    console.log(typeof timeCreated) //string
                    console.log(timeNow + "timeNow")
                    console.log(timeCreated + "timeCreated")
                    if (timeCreated <= timeNow) {
                        console.log("check") //this works well

                    Products.update({_id: productId}, {$set: {isItReady: true}}, function(error, result) {
                        console.log(productId) //all good
                        if (error){
                            console.log(error.reason) //check the error
                        } else{
                            console.log("File with the id: " + result + " just get update")
                        }

                    });
                    }
                  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of polling MongoDB every 5 seconds is very non-Meteoric. You'd be much better off creating a `Tracker.autorun` function to instantly react to any product that has `isItReady == false`

For example:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  var notReadyProducts = Products.find({ isItReady: false });
  notReadyProducts.forEach(function(p){
    if ( your logic ... ) Products.update({ _id: p._id },{ $set: { isItReady: true }});
  });
});
```

This assumes by the way that you're publishing (on the server) and subscribing to (on the client) a set of `Products` that is going to include these not ready products.

With this pattern no code will be running 99.99% of the time and then at the precise moment that a product is made not ready this code will kick in.

You might want to [take a look at this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUz8rr6jewU) to learn more about reactive programming and how it completely changes the way you approach common problems. There are many other resources available as well.

Comment: Hello and thanks you for the answer. I agree with you on the approach, reactive programming is much better.

I tried and created this function:

`Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var notReadyProducts = Products.findOne({isItReady: false});
  var productId = notReadyProducts._id;
  notReadyProducts.forEach(function(productId){
    if (1 < 2) {
      Products.update({_id: productId}, {$set: {isItReady: true}});
    }
  })
});`

But this gives me error which you can find here: https://gist.github.com/evilhei/9ff271f7a072baf9ac17

Comment: Can you make up a simple meteorpad example? The error without the rest of your code doesn't help that much. http://meteorpad.com/

Comment: Sure here you are. Basically I didn't need to add much before I get the error - http://meteorpad.com/pad/jtaiyg6WZ5q7nwnC5/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard

Comment: `Tracker.autorun` can only be used on the client. See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker

Comment: Also your meteorpad didn't publish (from the server) or subscribe (from the client) to the Products collection.

Comment: If your goal is to do this periodic update on the server then the simplest solution is to use the https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron package